# 405 - method not allowed calling web service from struts

Tags: java, struts2

I have a data access object which calls a web service. In my browser I can hit the web service using a url and it is successful.

```
http://mycompany:9080/ReportingManager/service/repManHealth/importHistoryTrafficLightStatus.json
```

[image]

But when  try to execute the code below in my data access object I get a 405 error saying method not allowed.

```
String requestURI = "http://mycompany:9080/ReportingManager/service/repManHealth/importHistoryTrafficLightStatus.json";
URL url = new URL(requestURI);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
httpCon.getOutputStream());

int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
String responseMessage = httpCon.getResponseMessage();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
rd.close();

String jsonResponse = sb.toString();

out.close();
httpCon.disconnect();
```

Can someone help me with what might be wrong here?

Also maybe there is a better way to execute a web service to an external application and read the response using struts? Or do people think this method is okay?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at the difference between your `Accept` and the Browsers `Accept`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your ideas however non of them were quite right. I fixed the 405 using the code below...

```
    String requestURI = "http://myserver:9080/ReportingManager/service/repManHealth/importHistoryTrafficLightStatus.json";
    URL url = new URL(requestURI);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If u are using GET method. Try the below code.

```
string url = String.Format("http://somedomain.com/samplerequest?greeting={0}",param);

WebClient serviceRequest = new WebClient();
serviceRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
string response = serviceRequest.DownloadString(new Uri(url));
```

Comment: But the controller I am calling is accepting get. Will it still work?

Comment: Can u provide me the screenshot of response and JSON like the image you have provided in ur question

Comment: Use HttpWebRequest instead of HttpURLConnection

Comment: What is the full import for WebClient?

Comment: What jar/ package is WebClient from?

Comment: Use NUGET library package and add System.Net.Http all on top

Answer (score -1):

By calling `httpCon.getOutputStream());` you're not sending a `HTTP GET` anymore, but a `HTTP POST`.

**Note:** This is under the assumption you end up getting the implementation provided by [Sun](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream%28%29). Which will change GET to POST for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I send a get request because I know the json controller is for a get operation

Comment: Remove `httpCon.setDoOutput(true);` and `OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
httpCon.getOutputStream());` and you should be good to go. :)

Comment: Are you sure about this.  The outputstream is inherited from the underlying URLConnection.

Comment: java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)